# Balance columns on last page of two-column article

Tags: two-column, lineno

[image]

I am working on the two column document. I am using the `flushend` package to automatically balance the columns on the last page. If I add the `lineno` package, the last page is not balanced.

If I remove the `lineno` package, it works as expected. Is there an incompatibility between these two packages?

If I use `\begin{multicols}{2}` instead of `\twocolumn`, the problem does not occur, but I faced more issues with floats.

Below is the file I used. Please check and suggest any ways to fix this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{flushend}

\usepackage{lineno}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\twocolumn

\begin{document}

\title{Application of Fuzzy-Rough Approach in Tractor Selection}


\linenumbers 

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately both packages patch the output routine of LaTeX. Maybe because `lineno` uses `\AtBeginDocument` to patch `\@makecol` it wins even if you'd load `lineno` before `flushend`. BTW: `lineno` is usually not used for the final document. If this is also true in your case, I'd suggest to just ignore the issue and remove `lineno` to generate the final document.